# D3 Angular 2 TypeError: Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, typescript-typings

Im trying to use d3.js (v3) in angular 2. Basically, I'm trying to take this streaming line chart [here](http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/6634070)

All I want to do is render it in a component. I've come to realize that D3 even with the typings installed doesn't work well with typescript. My problem here is that I can't figure out why it won't recognize domain here. I get the following:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined
```

Here's the relevant code. I'm sure there's some way i can define the type of x as 'any' to get this to work or something similar, but I can't figure out how in this example.

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
 .domain([<any>now - (limit - 2), <any>now - duration])
 .range([0, width])
//this below portion happens later, which you can see in the referenced code
x.domain([now - (limit - 2) * duration, now - duration]) //error occurs here
```

When I do `console.log(x)` directly after x is first initialized, I get this as output;

```
ƒ scale(x) {
  return linear(x);
}
```

And I get the exact same thing when logging x directly before calling x.domain. clearly x is set to a function. Im assuming the return value for that function includes the domain function? Why is this problematic in Typescript but not regular js?

Comment: Where do you get the error? At TypeScript compile time, or in the console? Do you maybe have a plnkr or jsfiddle or gist? Or even a git repo (I know getting TypeScript to work in-browser is not that easy...)

Comment: It's in the console. It seems to compile fine. The page loads and everything, the error occurs as soon as that last line executes. I don't have anything available like that unfortunately.

Comment: Then I would check the scope of your x variable, which is either not initialized when the second line gets executed, or already released.

Comment: I added some more information to the original question. It looks like the x variable I'm accessing is the exact same as what i originally initialized.

Comment: This seems weird... There is no reason for it to work in js but not ts. Did you try setting a breakpoint in code to see what's going on? Could you maybe paste the whole class code in your post?